# Java WebDriver Copy text Issue

Tags: java, copy, webdriver

Good Afternoon,

So I am trying to Copy some text from a field so I can paste it somewhere else in my test.

```
public static void validateTestCaseCreated(){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainForm:testTitle']")).click();
    Action builder;
    Actions copy = new Actions(driver);
    copy.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
    copy.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "c");
    builder = copy.build();
    builder.perform();
```

The problem when it reaches line 6 it only sends c, it ignores the CONTROL. So my end result is not copying the text but highlighting the text then entering c.

Comment: I think it is a neat thing to try to use a Action to do a copy paste but I see no benefit from creating such a test.  Everyone knows copy/paste is a operating system function that always works.  A better test would be just to simply verify the target field can have its value set.  We know from experience that copying from a source field will ALWAYS work and need not be tested either.  So, this test can be greatly simplified and does not require an Action be defined to do so.

Comment: Ok so let me elaborate a bit more. The end result of this test is to verify I have created a test case in a tool my team is building. The reason I have to copy paste is because I am randomizing the title of the test case and the only way to track said test case is to copy the title that is randomly generated and paste it into a title search field on a different page. I am not testing the copy paste functions themselves. I also have the task of automating every test possible.

Comment: Why can't you use a regular WebElement with CSS locator to set the value of the target field.  Why do you have to paste it?  Also, why can't you just retrieve the field value from the source field instead of using a "cntrl-c" copy?

Answer (score 1):

You could just copy the value from the text field into a variable and store it for use later.

Pull it from the page using your code along with the get attribute method.

```
String valueInField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainForm:testTitle']")).getAttribute("value");
```

That will grab the text from the field and put it into the variable for later use.

I'm not sure if this is doing fully what you are trying to do, seeing as you are trying to do a crtl+c, but this method is how to grab text using webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

If your field is an input element, maybe you can do something like this instead:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainForm:testTitle']")).click().get_attribute("value");
```